# Ctrl+Alt+Fin in Remote Desktop connection inside a vm

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop

i am using a VM inside a VM with remote .
and i am trying to use Ctrl+Alt+Fin, but it only works on the first VM MACHINE
and i am trying to use it on the second vm.
help will be appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the On-Screen Keyboard (osk.exe). You can press Ctrl-Alt-Del virtually from your first VM.